# Typescript does not properly infer this.props inside HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Consider following dummy HOC

```
interface SelectOption {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

interface HOCProps {
  value: string | SelectOption;
}

const testHOC = <P extends HOCProps>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>): React.ComponentType<P> =>
  class Wrapper extends React.Component<P> {
    constructor(props: P) {
      super(props);
      console.log(this.props.value);
      console.log(props.value);
  }

  render() {
    return <Component {...this.props} />;
  }
};
```

Typescript recognize `props.value` as expected:

> (property) HOCProps.value: string | SelectOption

But in `this.props.value` I got different result:

> (property) value: P["value"]

How can I fix the type annotation so that typescript will properly infer `this.props` ?
p.s. [codesanbox link to the code in question](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-4wrpg)

Comment: Does adding annotation for HOC return value help? Something like this - `(Component: React.ComponentType<P>): React.Component<P>`

Comment: @MukeshSoni Nope

Comment: `this.props` seems to be inferred correctly, although the typescript's type hinting seems to display this useless accessor `P["value"]` instead of the actual definition type. TS compiles and guards are working as expected. 
I have no idea why the actual type definition doesn't show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you see a difference between `this.props` and `props` in your constructor is, that they are in fact different types.

`props` is typed as `P` in the constructor, while `this.props` is defined in `React.Component` as `props: Readonly<P> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode }>;`

`Readonly` is defined in the typescript library as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), therefor you see while hovering `P["value"]` as this is pulled from the mapped type.

This issue has been raised with the typescript maintainers, [multiple](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15756) [times](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18089) and been [fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18042).

But the engine, displaying a type to you can for some reason not resolve these mapped types.

With JetBrains IntelliJ, the types resolve correctly, while in codesandbox I only see the unresolved type `P["value"]` which referes to the mapped type...

[image: example screenshot]

The problem can also be seen in this minimal example:

```js
interface Base {
  value: string | number;
}

const test = <T extends Base>(a: T, b: Readonly<T>) => {
  console.log(a.value, b.value);
}
```

This is a known design limitation of typescript, according to the maintainers: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32932#issuecomment-522353713

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!